# Gson().tojson() returning {} braces

Tags: java, android-studio, gson

Please somebody help me to figure out the problem..I want to store **BluetoothDevice** object in to SharedPrefrences so that next time when I open the app not need to select the paring device again.For this I have to convert this **BluetoothDevice** object in to **String** variable and then store it in to SharedPrefrence for that I have used

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(selectedDevice,BluetoothDevice.class) ;
```

Where **selectedDevice** is an object of BluetoothDevice class. But after running the code I got the **{}** braces in json variable. Can anyone have any idea why this is happening.

Comment: Show us `BluetoothDevice` file by editing your question.

Comment: @rupinderjeet you can get it by import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost all of the properties in `android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice` are `static final`. So, these properties do not depend on an instance.

One `address` property is available and depends on the instance variable. You can just save this `address` property to your shared-preferences using `getAddress()`.

If bluetooth is enabled, you can, also, get device name with `getName()`.

So, I suggest you save something like this in your shared-preferences;

```
class BluetoothDeviceInformation {

    String address;
    String name;

    @RequiresPermission(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH)
    public BluetoothDeviceInformation (
        BluetoothDevice device
    ) {
        this.address = device.getAddress();
        this.name = device.getName();
    }
}
```

You can create this instance using:

```
BluetoothDeviceInformation deviceInformation = 
    new BluetoothDeviceInformation(selectedBluetoothDevice);
```

There are other methods like `getType()`, `getAlias()` etc. If you need their information, just add them to your `BluetoothDeviceInformation` class.

Comment: thanks for the help..I did it by storing the Mac address of remote device and then fetching Device by BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address); has solve my purpose

Comment: if it solves, how about upvoting and/or accepting the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are referring https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.java, it contains static fields but,

Java Serialization only serialize object's non-static and non-transient fields

[Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)

But if you really need it same way you can try:

```
BluetoothDevice selectedDevice = new BluetoothDevice();
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.excludeFieldsWithModifiers(java.lang.reflect.Modifier.TRANSIENT);
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
String json = gson.toJson(selectedDevice, BluetoothDevice.class);
```

Comment: still it's not working.  Address is not store. if you have any new finding please let me know.